# Is there a Visual Studio equivalent of Vim scrolloff or Emacs scroll-margin?

Tags: visual-studio, text-cursor

Is there a standard option built into Visual Studio to act like the [Vim `scrolloff` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scrolloff%27) or the [Emacs `scroll-margin` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Scrolling.html)?

The aim is for Visual Studio to always show at least *x* lines above and below the current point.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a suggestion. I am using a Vim emulator extension in visual studio called VsVim.  https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim I tried setting the scrolloff, and it didn't work, but according to the author of the plugging, if you request a feature, he may implement it. Could there be an emacs emulator that does implement scroll-margin? Maybe.

Comment: @HugoEstrada he implemented it :) I instinctively set the option and was shocked at it working.

Answer (score 3):

If you hold control when you use the arrow key for up/down, it'll scroll the text up/down without moving the cursor.

Also, there is a command called Edit.ScrollLineCenter which you can search for under tools/options/environment/keyboard & assign a hotkey to it.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of the "Split View" feature in Visual Studio

As in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z01zks9a(v=vs.71).aspx it says:

> ### Splitting the View
>
> A Code Editor can
>   be split into two separate parts for
>   easier editing.
>
> **To split a pane**
>
> 1. Click the splitter bar (located above the scroll bar).
> 2. Drag the splitter bar downward.
> 3. To go back to a single pane, double-click the splitter bar dividing the two panes.
>
> The new pane contains the same
>   document, and any changes made to it
>   are reflected in the other pane as
>   long as that pane displays the same
>   place in the document.

You can additionaly open a file in a new window (Menu `Window`>`New Window`) and dock it next to the original window to view additional different parts of that file simultaneously as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax(v=VS.90).aspx

> ### Tiling Document Windows
>
> If you want to view more than one document at a time while editing code,
>   you can tile the document windows.
>
> **To tile document windows**
>
> If the IDE is running in Tabbed documents mode, select a tab and drag it
>   below or above the current document tile. A rectangular outline appears
>   in the location where the new document tile will be placed.

Some screenshots for both options: http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2008/08/19/visual-studio-tip-split-views/

**Update:**

Does navigating with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> inside the editor window help you?

Comment: Very useful, but unfortunately not what we are looking for. With VI's behaviour you always get context around the cursor, without having to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `editor.cursorSurroundingLines` to your `settings.json`

e.g

```
"editor.cursorSurroundingLines": 8,
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: No there isn't.

Longer: No there isn't any that I am aware of.  But there should be.  Search the extensions and please report back.

Answer (score 0):

Way old answer, but anyway: there's an option now. Open UI Settings and search for `Cursor Surrounding Lines`. That's exactly what vim's `scrolloff` is.